# user 's screen's height & width to be saved in variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .net, user-interface

Can We Copy The height & Width of the screen of the viewer or user in variables like***

```
var h=?

var w=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var h=screen.height should do it.
Same with width.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
w = $(window).width(); //get current window width
h = $(window).height(); //get current window height
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way:

```
//page load
var windowW = $(window).width();
var windowH = $(window).height();

//window size change
$(window).resize(function() {
    windowW = $(window).width();
    windowH = $(window).height();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want?

```
var h = screen.height,
w = screen.width;
```